Doughnut chart from chartjs2 is not population data from another component in React JS
In my project I am trying to use doughnut chart as a separate component. I am passing some values from a component to the doughnut chart component. It is not showing the correct chart. I am passing the values from other component to the chart component as follows:
<DoughnutChart wrong={wrong} right={right} />

In the doughnutchart component the values are showing in the props but chart is not working.
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

  const DoughnutChart = (props) => {
  const chartRef = useRef(null);

  const curwrong = props.wrong;
  const curright = props.right;

  const chartdata = {

    labels: ['Wrong', 'Right'],
    datasets: [{
    data: [curwrong,curright],
    backgroundColor: ['rgb(197, 0, 0)', 'rgb(0, 223, 0)']
  }]

  };

  // Options for the chart
  const options = {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Exam Result'
      }
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    const data = chartdata;
    // Create the chart instance
    const myChart = new Chart(chartRef.current, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: data,
      options: options
    });

    // Clean up function to destroy the chart when component unmounts
    return () => myChart.destroy();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{width:300}}>
      <canvas ref={chartRef}></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DoughnutChart;

